# Украинские символы в Java

Tags: java, windows, кодировка, utf-8, cp1251

Столкнулся с проблемой некорректного перекодирования украинских символов 'і', 'ї', 'є', 'І', 'Ї', 'Є' из UTF-8 в windows-1251.

Есть код, который преобразует текст из windows-1251 в UTF-8:

```
connectToUrl = new String(connectToUrl.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");
```

часть этой строки вводится пользователем Windows с клавиатуры (имя музыкального исполнителя)

Далее совершается запрос на сайт (пример `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptracks&artist=Воплі%20Відоплясова&api_key=API_KEY)` и ожидается получение от него XML:

```
URL url = new URL(connectToUrl);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

Запрос проходит корректно при использовании латиницы и русской кириллицы, но, если в тексте встречается хотя бы один украинский символ, сайт не принимает строку запроса, как корректную.

При ручном вводе запроса в браузер все работает.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

**UPD:**

Вот кусок моего класса, отвечающего за GUI:

```
class AppGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    searchTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    searchTextField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            searchTextFieldKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    private void searchButtonMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // get user input 
        try {
            searchString = new String(searchTextField.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AppGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            infoField.setText("Unsupported encoding");
        }
        topTracks = new TopTracks(searchString, searchMethod).getTopTracks();
        if (searchTextField.getText().equals("") || topTracks == null) {
            infoField.setText("There is no such tag or artist");
    }
}
```

А это кусок класса, отвечающего за запрос к сайту и получение XML:

```
public class TopTracks {
public TopTracks(String searchString, String method) {

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/");
    buffer.append("?method=");
    buffer.append(method);
    if (method.equals("tag.gettoptracks")) {
        buffer.append("&tag=");
        buffer.append(searchString);
    } else if (method.equals("artist.gettoptracks")) {
        buffer.append("&artist=");
        buffer.append(searchString);
    }
    buffer.append("&limit=");
    buffer.append(LAST_FM_LIMIT_OF_TRACKS);
    buffer.append("&api_key=");
    buffer.append(LAST_FM_API_KEY);
    connectToUrl = buffer.toString();
    connectToUrl = connectToUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    try {
        URL url = new URL(connectToUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TopTracks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Unable to get data");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считывание строки `searchTextField.getText()`, судя по всему, правильное. Проблема возникает при конструировании URL.

В конструкторе `TopTracks` нужно код `buffer.append(searchString)` заменить, как советуют в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/276994), на такой:

```
buffer.append(URLEncoder.encode(searchString, "UTF-8"))
```

Заодно отпадает необходимость в ручной замене пробелов на `%20`: встроенный класс экранирует нужные символы автоматически.

Заметьте, что части запроса наподобие `&tag=` *не нужно* пропускать через `URLEncoder`, так как он закодирует символ `&`, что нам не нужно. (Заодно мы исправили баг в коде, не учитывающий возможного присутствия `&` в `searchString`.)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Теперь при выводе в консоль для проверки запрос к серверу выводится корректно, например: `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptracks&artist=%D0%A4%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82&limit=100&api_key=...`

Comment: @MaksimBudilovsky: Отлично! Проблема решена. Хорошо, что разобрались.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема у вас в том, что такой операции, как "преобразование кодировки строки", не существует. Строка в памяти всегда находится в кодировке UTF-16. Если вам надо сменить кодировку у строки - значит, в вашей программе ошибка: строка была некорректно считана. То, что вы делаете над `connectToUrl`, называется "костыль" и "пляски с бубном".

**UPD:**
Вы все равно делаете что-то странное. Откуда у вас в `searchTextField` оказались символы в неправильной кодировке? Или зачем вам в `searchString` неправильная кодировка символов? Все должно работать вот так:

```
searchString = searchTextField.GetText()
```

Если так не работает - значит, проблема в другом месте.

Comment: "что в кодировке windows-1251 попросту нет украинских букв - потому что это, вообще-то, русская кодировка!" вообще-то она называется кириллической, а не русской. Ну и перечисленные в вопросе символы там есть.

Comment: cp1251 [содержит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) все символы украинского, белорусского, сербского, македонского и болгарского.

По поводу "строка всегда находится в кодировке utf-16" - также бред.

Comment: Насчет букв символов согласен, они на месте, хотя найти их оказалось трудно.

Comment: По поводу же utf-16 - сомневающиеся могут поискать представление типов данных `char` и `String` в памяти компьютера.

Comment: Решил вопрос считыванием той части строки, что пользователь вводит с клавиатуры сразу в UTF-8: `searchString = new String(searchTextField.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));` и потом уже делаю append к `connectToUrl`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я дополнил свой вопрос рабочими экземплярами кода. Все варианты, которые пробовал до этого - не работали. Работоспособным оказался только такой вариант. Хотя вариант `searchString = searchTextField.GetText()` должен был работать нормально. Сегодня еще проверю.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал решить вопрос считыванием той части строки, что пользователь вводит с клавиатуры сразу в UTF-8:

`searchString = new String(searchTextField.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));`

и потом уже делаю append к `connectToUrl`. Так работает.

Comment: Что-то не то. Это похоже не на решение, а на workaround. Почему `searchTextField.getText()` выдаёт неправильную строку? Или строка правильная, а проблема в другом месте? Проверьте.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, проверю

Comment: Попробовал использовать `searchString = searchTextField.getText(); ` - в результате запросы с кириллицей сервер перестал воспринимать. Объяснить, почему - не могу. Костыль, не костыль, а помогло только прямое указание считывать `searchTextField` как набор UTF-8 символов.

Comment: Подождите. А вы просто проверьте, правильная ли строка получается по `.getText()`. Как и что работает — это проблема интеграции, а нас интересует, где конкретно ошибка. Вот сейчас мы пытаемся выяснить, ошибка в `.getText()` или где-то ещё.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(searchString.getBytes()));` результат для Pearl Jam: [80, 101, 97, 114, 108, 32, 74, 97, 109], результат для Сплин: [-47, -17, -21, -24, -19]

Comment: При этом, если перед этим написать `searchString = new String(searchTextField.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));` , то результат для "Сплин" будет [-48, -95, -48, -65, -48, -69, -48, -72, -48, -67], и сервер примет запрос нормально

Comment: `.getBytes()` неинтересно. Вы скажите, нормальная ли там строка? Поставьте breakpoint и посмотрите значение переменной.

Comment: Подождите, что?? Тут уже совсем непонятно. То есть вы имеете в виду, что `searchString.еquals(new String(searchString.getBytes("UTF-8"))`?

Comment: Тем более, если проблема с украинскими символами, то напишите не "Сплин", а "Плач Єремії", там много специфических букв.

Comment: Нет, это разные строки, вроде. Поставил брейкпойт. При `searchTextField.getText()` переменная принимает значение "Сплин", при `searchString.getBytes("UTF-8")` - "РЎРїР»РёРЅ"

Comment: Отлично. Значит, getText() даёт всё правильно. Одну точку мы проверили, идёмте дальше. Где вы конструируете запрос для сервера?

Comment: В конце вопроса я привел куски кода - searchString передается в метод, который составляет запрос и отправляет его серверу

Comment: Ага, это конструктор `TopTracks`, да?

Comment: Да, именно конструктор

Comment: Проблема с украинскими символами была, когда я перекодировал строку запроса целиком, Сейчас я перекодирую, по сути, только часть, которая может быть написана кириллицей

Comment: Ага, вы просто сливаете всё вместе и говорите `new URL`. Попробуйте в той точке как рекомендуют [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/276994): вместо `buffer.append(searchString)` такое: `buffer.append(URLEncoder.encode(searchString, "UTF-8"))`.

Comment: Заодно вам не придётся вручную заменять пробелы.

Comment: Благодарю, это то, что нужно! Я просто не знал о существовании URLEncoder

Comment: По сути он и занимается тем, что переводит из UTF-8 в кодировку текущей ОС, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Наоборот, он кодирует символы строки в UTF-8, и заменяет «опасные» символы (то есть, те, которые не передадутся просто так) на HTML escape. Так что итоговая строка получается по сути в ASCII.

Comment: Отлично, тогда давайте оформлю в ответ.

Comment: Давайте, Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Готово, собрал дискуссию в ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Вам не кажется (я про отвечающих в том числе), что вы занимаетесь какой-то фигней? Неужели в жаве нельзя сделать так:

```
requests.get("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/", params={
    "method": "artist.gettoptracks",
    "artist": "Воплі Відоплясова",
    "api_key": API_KEY,
})
```

Все замечательно читается даже без знания языка и не надо ничего руками экранировать, также один запрос - один вызов функции.